# For loop of Hashmap to ArrayList is not holding the correct values. How to fix?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, simpleadapter

I have the following code which surprisingly doesn't work;

```
     needsInfoView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.needsInfo);
            needsInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
            HashMap<String, String> needsInfoHashMap = new HashMap<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                needsInfoHashMap.put("TA", needsTitleArray[i]);
                needsInfoHashMap.put("IA", needsInfoArray[i]);
                Log.e("NIMH",needsInfoHashMap.toString());
//Here, I get the perfect output - TA's value, then IA's value
                needsInfoList.add(needsInfoHashMap);
                Log.e("NIL",needsInfoList.toString());
//This is a mess - TA, IA values for 12 entries are all the same, they are the LAST entries of needsTitleArray and needsInfoArray on each ArrayList item.

                needsInfoAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), needsInfoList,
                        R.layout.needsinfocontent, new String[]{ "TA", "IA"},
                        new int[]{R.id.ta, R.id.ia});
                needsInfoView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
                needsInfoView.setAdapter(needsInfoAdapter);
            }
```

Please see the comment below the log lines. That explains the output I receive. How do I make the ArrayList values pass to the two text fields in my ListView via the SimpleAdapter?

Thank you

Comment: HashMap is designed for uniqueness and if you are trying to add the same key with previous , then it will update the key value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For loop of `Hashmap` to `ArrayList` is not holding the correct values

Because your are adding same instance `HashMap` in your `needsInfoList`

You need to add new  instance `HashMap` in your `needsInfoList` list like below code

**Also** you need to set your `needsInfoAdapter` to your `needsInfoView`  `listview` outside the loop like below code

Try this

```
needsInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
needsInfoView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.needsInfo);

  for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
       HashMap<String, String> needsInfoHashMap = new HashMap<>();
       needsInfoHashMap.put("TA", needsTitleArray[i]);
       needsInfoHashMap.put("IA", needsInfoArray[i]);
       needsInfoList.add(needsInfoHashMap);
   }
   needsInfoAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), needsInfoList,
                R.layout.needsinfocontent, new String[]{"TA", "IA"},
                new int[]{R.id.ta, R.id.ia});
   needsInfoView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
   needsInfoView.setAdapter(needsInfoAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same `HashMap` instance multiple times to the `List`, which means the entries you put in the `Map` on each iteration replace the entries put by the previous iteration.

You should create a new `HashMap` instance on each iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> needsInfoHashMap = new HashMap<>();
    needsInfoHashMap.put("TA", needsTitleArray[i]);
    needsInfoHashMap.put("IA", needsInfoArray[i]);
    needsInfoList.add(needsInfoHashMap);
    ....
}
```